# How to highlight active row in excel and then return to base background color in VBA

Tags: excel, user-controls, imacros, vba

How do you highlight an active row in excel in VBA. and then when another row is selected, return that row to base background color, and highlight the new row.

Also how to clear all rows highlighted, using a clear button on the user form.

so there are tow question here, one to high light and unhighlight active rows, and the other to just clear all high lights by pressing a clear button on the form.

I know I can highlight a row using Ret.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 but i cant find code to unhighlight.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your 'clear all' functionality before changing the color of the row of the cell that you navigated to.

Open the VB Editor and right click --> view code on the worksheet that you want the row highlighting to take place.

Paste in this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Me.Range("A1:XFD1048576").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End Sub
```

This code operates as follows:  whenever a user changes his or her selected cell(s) on the sheet, the code will first clear the existing highlighting away in the entire sheet and then will apply new highlighting to the row of the target cell the user has moved to.

This line of code:

`Worksheets("YourSheetName").Range("A1:XFD1048576").Interior.ColorIndex = 0`

Will clear the colors from all cells in the worksheet.

You may want to limit the `Range("A1:XFD1048576")` to the usable range on your workbook as this will increase performance.  On my machine I see a very subtle, but still noticeable, delay in the colors when I move the cells (because I am clearing all cells in the sheet instead of just the ones I want).  If you do this, you probably wouldn't want to use the `.EntireRow` attribute, instead you would have to enumerate how far along the workbook you want the row to be highlighted.

### Update

Try this code below, which eliminates the need to clear the entire worksheet.  I used `.ColorIndex=xlNone` instead of setting it to `0` which *should* preserve your table formatting.  I tested in Excel 2010 and I formatted some data as a table, it highlights the correct row and unhighlights the other row as well as leaving the table formatting in tact.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Static rr

    If rr <> "" Then
        With Rows(rr).Interior
            .ColorIndex = xlNone
        End With
    End If


    r = Selection.Row
    rr = r

    With Rows(r).Interior
        .ColorIndex = 6
        .Pattern = xlSolid
    End With
End Sub
```

The trick is using `Static`.  This allows the variable to continue to exist after termination of the procedure, so it remembers the last row it highlighted and then performs the un-highlight action accordingly.

The procedure first checks to see that `rr` is set, if it is not then it moves on, if it is then `rr` represents the row that was previously highlighted.

Comment: Thanks, that seems easy enough, the only problem I have with this is that the worksheet has a table format so each row has a different color. In other words row 1 would b eblue but row 2 would be white, and then row 3 would be  blue and row 4 would be white.  So if  I use the all clear for the entire workbook it would make all rows one color.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I will invite anyone else to contribute to your question and I will think a bit more on this one.

Comment: If you have a table format in there I believe you can use `xlNone` to just restore the formatting to the normal table.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Joshua I will try the static code. I did come up with a different way , which I will post here later toda, but I think I would like to try it your way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without changing the base background color,
In 2 steps,

1. Set up a conditional formatting rule that highlights an entire row if a certain formula is true.

> In the formula field, enter this formula:
>   =OR(CELL("row")=CELL("row",A1))
>   [image: Conditional formatting formula]

2. Write a macro that recalculates the selected cell(s) when a new selection is made.

> `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
>       Target.Calculate
>     End Sub`

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to get back to Excel and you'll have the active cell's row highlighted with the format you chose, without changing the base colors of the cells.

For detailed explanation visit,
[highlighted the entire row of the active cell.](http://www.thesmallman.com/blog/2016/9/15/auto-highlight-the-active-row-when-a-cell-is-selected)